# Validating in php form builder class

Tags: php, class, forms

How do you validate in php using php-form-builder-class from http://code.google.com/p/php-form-builder-class/

```
include("php-form-builder-class/class.form.php");
$form = new form("myform");
$form->setAttributes(array(
     "width" => 400
));

$form->addTextarea("My Textarea:", "MyTextarea" "", array("required"=> 1));
$form->addButton();
$form->render();
```

I want MyTextArea field to be limited to 400 characters, and this only adds javascript validation? How do I go about adding validation in php using this class?

Answer (score 0):

php validation, and the answer to the other questions are in the docs
http://www.imavex.com/php-form-builder-class/examples/validation.php

Comment: that uses this: if($form->validate()) {, which doesn't do anything for me if I disable javascript. They are very unclear on the usage.

Comment: well if you vote down my answer for pointing you to the manual which has the  answer, don't expect any follow up help.

Comment: I did that by accident, and @johnmossel the answer is in the manual